# How to import my own class or method globally in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a class and method that I need to import globally, so that I could avoid importing it again in each Vue file. I usually import my own class and method in each Vue file like this:

```js
// in myFunc.js
export const fn = {
  myFunc: function(param) { alert(param) }
}

// then I use it like this
import {fn} from '@/assets/js/myFunc.js';
fn.myFunc('Lorem ipsum');
```

In `main.js`, I tried the following code, which does not work:

```js
import {fn} from '@/assets/js/myFunc.js';

Vue.mixin({
  components: { fn },
})
```

How do I import the class/methods globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { fn } from '@/assets/js/myFunc.js';

Vue.prototype.$fn = fn
```

And then in your component.

```js
this.$fn.myFunc()
```

[Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html).

> There may be data/utilities you’d like to use in many components, but
> you don’t want to pollute the global scope. In these cases, you can
> make them available to each Vue instance by defining them on the
> prototype.

Comment: `this.$fn.myFunc(); ` it's work, by the way, can we call the method without write `this.$fn.myFunc()`  just `myFunc()` ??,

Comment: Yes, to achieve that you should polute global object (`window` in browser - `window.myFunc = function() { console.log('I am in the global scope!') }`). But it's considered a bad practise.